# LocalExecutor or CeleryExecutor for Airflow on a single machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, celery

My question may sound dumb, but we have a ETL process running in a remote machine (EC2) and as we only use it internally in the company and there are only 5 of us, we set up Airflow with Docker following the official tutorial (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) where it is set up with a CeleryExecutor.

Fast forward to today, we have some problems of memory in our machine, the airflow worker seems to shut down due to too much overload (I guess). And now we are wondering if we should keep Airflow with a CeleryExecutor or if we should opt for a LocalExecutor ? As it makes no sense to have a CeleryExecutor in a single machine. But why would the tutorial use CeleryExecutor then ?

If we should move to a LocalExecutor, what are the benefits and how to do it with a docker-compose image ?